Why is there an option to share my network connection with others?
Just curious why this option exists and is enabled by default ?


Suppose this is your home computer. You have 3 users, your child, spouse, and you. Everyone wants to connect to the home Wi-Fi. Do you want to set up the Wi-Fi connection 3 times or once?

Linux is designed to be a multi-user system. This checkbox allows other users on your system to use the network, or should the connection be dropped when you logout. Check ✔️  the box. No biggie.
